# Swagger-UI :: Access to fetch at 'Server URL' from origin blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request

Tags: cors, salesforce, swagger-ui, openapi, swagger-2.0

I have REST API on salesforce.com and I want to document it with swagger-ui. I am trying this using SpringBoot 2.7.12, I have added springfox-swagger2, springfox-swagger-ui, springfox-swagger-common all these dependencies has version 2.9.2.

I have added swagger.json file in src/main/resources, I am able to launch the swagger-ui with given api but when it comes to execute it, I am getting below error on broser,

Error:

Access to fetch at 'https://login.salesforce.com/services/oauth2/token' from origin 'http://localhost:8080' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.

can someone please help to identify what is wrong in the json file or how I can set 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header. I have enabled CORS on salesforce org but it is still not working.

Below is my swagger.json file.

```
{
    "swagger": "2.0",
    "info": {
        "description": "Demo",
      "version": "1.0.0",
        "title": "Test Account API",
        "termsOfService": "http://swagger.io/terms/",
        "contact": {
            "email": "apiteam@swagger.io"
        },
        "license": {
            "name": "Apache 2.0",
            "url": "http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0.html"
        }
    },
    "host": "********************-dev-ed.my.salesforce.com",
    "basePath": "/services/apexrest",
    "tags": [
        {
            "name": "accountapi",
            "description": "Everything about your Accounts",
            "externalDocs": {
                "description": "Find out more",
                "url": "http://swagger.io"
            }
        }
    ],
    "schemes": [
        "https",
        "http"
    ],
    "paths": {
        "/account": {
            "post": {
                "tags": [
                    "accountapi"
                ],
                "summary": "Create new Account",
                "description": "Creating new Accounr",
                "operationId": "createAccount",
                "consumes": [
                    "application/json",
                    "application/xml"
                ],
                "produces": [
                    "application/json",
                    "application/xml"
                ],
                "parameters": [
                    {
                        "in": "body",
                        "name": "body",
                        "description": "Account Details to be added",
                        "required": true,
                        "schema": {
                            "$ref": "#/definitions/Accounts"
                        }
                    }
                ],
                "responses": {
                    "405": {
                        "description": "Invalid input"
                    }
                },
                "security": [
                    {
                        "salesforce_auth": [
                            "write:accounts",
                            "read:accounts"
                        ]
                    }
                ]
            }
        },
        "/account/{accountName}": {
            "get": {
                "tags": [
                    "accountapi"
                ],
                "summary": "Fetching account by name",
                "description": "Get Account by name",
                "operationId": "getAccountByName",
                "produces": [
                    "application/json",
                    "application/xml"
                ],
                "parameters": [
                    {
                        "name": "accountName",
                        "in": "path",
                        "description": "Account name that need to be fetched. ",
                        "required": true,
                        "type": "string"
                    }
                ],
                "responses": {
                    "200": {
                        "description": "successful operation",
                        "schema": {
                            "$ref": "#/definitions/Accounts"
                        }
                    },
                    "400": {
                        "description": "Invalid account supplied"
                    },
                    "404": {
                        "description": "quote not found"
                    },
                    "401": {
                        "description": "Un-Authorized Access"
                    }
                },
                "security": [
                    {
                        "salesforce_auth": [
                            "write:accounts",
                            "read:accounts"
                        ]
                    }
                ]
            }
        }
    },
    "securityDefinitions": {
        "salesforce_auth": {
            "type": "oauth2",
            "tokenUrl": "https://login.salesforce.com/services/oauth2/token",
            "flow": "password",
            "scopes": {
                "read:accounts": "read accounts",
                "write:accounts": "modify accounts"
            }
        }
    },
    "definitions": {
        "Accounts": {
            "type": "object",
            "properties": {
                "name": {
                    "type": "string"
                },
                "phone": {
                    "type": "string"
                },
                "website": {
                    "type": "string"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you [enable CORS for Salesforce OAuth endpoints](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.remoteaccess_oauth_endpoints_cors.htm&type=5) and add `http://localhost:8080` [to the allowlist](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.extend_code_cors.htm&type=5)?

Comment: Yes, I added http://localhost:8080 and enabled the CORS for salesforce OAuth endpoint. But that did not resolve my issue.